# working with the latest token sent in my web service

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem to find the latest token .. back end make the token change in every request so if I use it once it turned to be invalid in the next time, and they send the next valid token in Authorization header.

I am trying to get the latest token.

```
+(void)askServerUsingToken:(void (^)(NSDictionary * json,bool isSuccess))completionBlock{
//    NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseURL,action];
    //check token
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *token = [defaults stringForKey:@"token"];
    if (token!= nil) {
        NSString *finalyToken = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",token];
        NSString *profile=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@profile?token=%@",baseURL,finalyToken];
        NSLog(@"%@",profile);
        AFHTTPSessionManager *manager=[AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        manager.responseSerializer=[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        [manager.requestSerializer setValue:finalyToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
        [manager GET:profile parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //        NSError *errorJson=nil;
                //        NSDictionary *jsonList=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&errorJson];
                NSDictionary *jsonList=(NSDictionary*)responseObject;
                //            completionBlock(jsonList,true);
                if (jsonList !=nil) {
                    completionBlock(jsonList,true);
                }else{
                    completionBlock(jsonList,false);
                }

            });
        }failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                completionBlock(nil,false);
            });
        }];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"no token");
    }`enter code here`

}
```

Comment: Please do not post code as a picture. Please replace the picture with actual code, copied and pasted as text, into your question. Images can't be searched and the code can't be referenced, and it is harder to read.

Comment: can you please provide a api url so that we can check?

Comment: @NaGibToroNgo 
http://mkssab.com/api/login
login >mona password>123456
http://mkssab.com/api/profile?token=

Comment: @NaGibToroNgo ??

Comment: did you tried this `- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)HEAD:(NSString *)URLString
                    parameters:(id)parameters
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task))success
                       failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error))failure`